# how to make " request.user.is_authenticated" work without throwing an error

Tags: django

i have tried to use the authentication of a user but every time i use it i get a type error telling me that the 'bool' object is not callable.
I can't get over it.

```
 if request.user.is_authenticated():
        print(user)
    else:
        return redirect("/login")
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

Answer (score 2):

In newer versions of Django, the [**`is_authenticated`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated) becomes a ***attribute*** rather instead of ***function***. 
So use ***`request.user.is_authenticated`*** (with out the paranthesis "()" )

```
#Code snippet
if request.user.is_authenticated: # change is here <<<<<<<
        print(user)
    else:
        return redirect("/login")
    return render(request, 'h/code>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you receive an error saying `x is not callable` it's usually because you're trying to call something that is not a function. For instance,

```
myVar = True
myVar()
```

would return the same error as above.

In your case, `request.user.is_authenticated()` needs to be replaced with `request.user.is_authenticated` ( minus the brackets ) since `request.user.is_authenticated` is an attribute, not a function.

Cheers!